# How to configure window switching functionality?

Tags: 11.04, unity

The currently selected window is hard to tell, most of the time I have to look at the title of the selected window in the top bar, there is no highlights on the selected window, how to fix that?

Comment: Do you mean, when using Alt-tab? Or clicking twice on an icon in the launcher? (Or Super+w?)

Comment: I mean using [Super]+s

Answer (score 1):

When using Super-S, the currently selected window is the one on top.

However, what I think you mean is "the current workspace" - as far as I know, there is no way to change how to do that in the `ccsm` package, however, I've been known to be wrong from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

The currently selected window is the one that has one arrow on either side of it (on the launcher). Other windows have a single arrow on the left side.

Example:

[image: Selected]
**Selected window.**

[image: De-selected]
**Deselected window.**