# LightDM won't start after Grub - Cannot Access TTY unless closing and re-opening lid

Tags: 14.04, ati, lightdm

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 on an hp envy 17 3D. New installation + ATI Drivers

I would appreciate some help troubleshooting what I think is a LightDM issue which I have not been able to solve.

When I boot the computer after selecting Ubuntu at grub - the laptop seems to go through the regular boot process. The screen will flicker a second and I will hear the login screen prompt, but the login screen will not appear.

Attempting to switch to TTY mode will make the screen flicker again. I am able to run commands - but i cannot see the terminal. I have successfully rebooted, and attempted to start lightdm this way, but after running:

```
sudo service lightDM restart
```

It shows me the desktop background and cursor and just hangs.

I am able to still use the computer, if when I hear the login prompt, I close the lid to tell it to go to sleep, and then turn it back on. LightDM login shows up and I can use the computer normally.

Does this correctly seem like a lightdm issue? or is this xorg?
What logs should I be looking at to troubleshoot if I can only do so after putting the computer to sleep before logging in? What should I be looking for in those logs based on the issue above?

Thanks!

[Update]
If I attempt to logout, the same issue happens. I hear the Ubuntu login screen chime, but cannot see the login screen or switch to a TTY or login by typing. I can though shutdown by pressing the power button then enter.

I followed this bug to see if it applied, adding a sleep to start of lightdm and telling it to wait for udev, while this has prolonged the time it takes to hear the chime, it has not made the login screen appear. 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/1066410

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of installing the beta, I followed the instructions here for installing via command line.

I also followed the instructions here for some troubleshooting to remove all errors
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD

Then I looked through some x.org logs to find any errors.

Following these two posts helped clear those errors up
https://askubuntu.com/questions/46524...ossfirex-in-ub
https://askubuntu.com/questions/94272.../175677#175677

As of this morning with a hard reboot, it is back to normal